# Checking files for errors

Tags: windows, filesystems

I have lots of files in different formats (mostly pdf files) and I need to check if they can be opened without errors and get a list of those that are broken.

Other than opening them all separately is there a way to find out which won't open / are corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no.  Because there are so many file types it would be impossible to know if a file was corrupt without opening it.  It might open without errors but still be corrupt so even that isn't going to help you.  You could try a general file opening solution like  [KeyView](http://www.autonomy.com/content/Products/idol-modules-keyview-viewing/index.en.html) which can open most file formats.  If it fails then chances are the file is corrupt.